# R Shiny: Does the Input object store the type of input

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a parameter file for my app that the user can upload to re-populate all input fields with the inputs they had used in a previous session.

I know I can get the names and values of all the inputs using `reactiveValuesToList(input)`, but does the 'input' object store the kind of input (text, slider, radioButtons, etc.) anywhere? I'm hoping that there's an easy way to identify the type so I can use the correct update*Input function without using a daisy chain of tryCatches.

Also, is there any way I can learn more about the structure of the input object? Using `str(input)` isn't really helpful, and I was wondering if there was any good documentation on what all the parts mean and where to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the advanced features of shiny can be found in one of the articles here:

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/

You can also find the reference here for all the functions:
https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/

What you are trying to do is very similar to bookmarking your app. It is possible that the functionnality you are looking for is already implemented:
https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/enableBookmarking.html

Otherwise, if it does not do the trick, you can use `session` and the `onSessionEnded` function to save a table with your parameter as it is when closing then use that table to initialise your parameter when the user connect again.

Comment: Thank you, this is great info!